# Creating list of matrices in R

Tags: r, finance

```
> fact.cov <- matrix(NA,ncol(fact.weight),ncol(fact.weight))

> for (row in 15:nrow(fact.weight)) {
    >> fact.cov[[row]] <- var(fact.wealth.return[(row-1):row,])
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

```
Error in fact.cov[[row]] <- var(fact.wealth.return[(row - 1):row, ]) : 
  more elements supplied than there are to replace
```

For each point in time (row), I need to create a covariance matrix. Do someone knows how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to create a Cov matrix or a list of matrices?

Comment: List of matrices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be helpful:

```
fact.cov <- list()
for (k in 15:fact.weight) {
 fact.cov[[k]] <- var(fact.wealth.return[(k-1):k,])    
};rm(k)
```

However, you should provide more details in order for your code to be reproduceable (e.g. what is `fact.wealth.return` or `fact.weight`).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly you seek to accomplish without understanding your data. But you can easily create an empty list, and then assign a matrix to each of the list's elements, thus obtaining a list of matrices. I would encourage creating an empty list of determined size, because this is generally a better use of memory and can be faster.

```
listOfMatrices <- vector("list", 10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  listOfMatrices[[i]] <- matrix(NA, nrow=2, ncol=3)
}
```

The output of this will be a list of length `10`, and each element of this list will be a matrix with `2` rows and `3` columns. Each matrix will be populated by `NA`s.